# $(^name) error while installing Android Studio Beta

Tags: android, sdk, adt, android-studio, beta

Does anyone who has installed Android Studio collided in to "$(^name) stop working" error?
I tried to install it in a Windows 7 64bits.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install JDK 32 bits version, restart and install.